# Insert a new element in an existing array in JSON using SQL Server script

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

How can I append an element in an existing array in JSON using SQL? I want to update the Fruits object and want to insert a new element in the existing array.

Here's the JSON I want to Update.

```
    {
    "Heading": [
        {
            "Index": 1,
            "Name": "Empty"
        },
        {
            "Index": 2,
            "Name": "TypeOfFruit"
        },
        {
            "Index": 3,
            "Name": "Color"
        },
        {
            "Index": 3,
            "Name": "Taste"
        }
    ],
    "Fruits": [
        {
            "Column1": "",
            "Column2": "Mango",
            "Column3": "Yellow"
        },
        {
            "Column1": "",
            "Column2": "Coconut",
            "Column3": "Green"
        },
        {
            "Column1": "",
            "Column2": "Banana",
            "Column3": "Yellow"
        },
        {
            "Column1": "",
            "Column2": "Apple",
            "Column3": "Red"
        },
        {
            "Column1": "",
            "Column2": "Watermelon",
            "Column3": "Green"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the after that I want after the update. I want to insert the element "Column4": "Sweet" in the Fruits object existing arrays.

```
    {
    "Heading": [
        {
            "Index": 1,
            "Name": "Empty"
        },
        {
            "Index": 2,
            "Name": "TypeOfFruit"
        },
        {
            "Index": 3,
            "Name": "Color"
        },
        {
            "Index": 3,
            "Name": "Taste"
        }
    ],
    "Fruits": [
        {
            "Column1": "",
            "Column2": "Mango",
            "Column3": "Yellow"
            "Column4": "Sweet"
        },
        {
            "Column1": "",
            "Column2": "Coconut",
            "Column3": "Green"
            "Column4": "Sweet"
        },
        {
            "Column1": "",
            "Column2": "Banana",
            "Column3": "Yellow"
            "Column4": "Sweet"
        },
        {
            "Column1": "",
            "Column2": "Apple",
            "Column3": "Red"
            "Column4": "Sweet"
        },
        {
            "Column1": "",
            "Column2": "Watermelon",
            "Column3": "Green"
            "Column4": "Sweet"
        },
        
    ]
}
```

Here is the code that I'm using and want to know if there's something I'm missing here.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX), @appendnewjson VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = '{"Heading":[{"Index":1,"Name":"Empty"},{"Index":2,"Name":"TypeOfFruit"},{"Index":3,"Name":"Color"},{"Index":3,"Name":"Taste"}],"Fruits":[{"Column1":"","Column2":"Mango","Column3":"Yellow"},{"Column1":"","Column2":"Coconut","Column3":"Green"},{"Column1":"","Column2":"Banana","Column3":"Yellow"},{"Column1":"","Column2":"Apple","Column3":"Red"},{"Column1":"","Column2":"Watermelon","Column3":"Green"}]}';
SET @appendnewjson='Column4:Sweet'
SELECT @json AS 'Before', 
    JSON_MODIFY(@json, 'append $.Fruits', @appendnewjson) AS 'After';
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX), @appendnewjson VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = '{"Heading":[{"Index":1,"Name":"Empty"},{"Index":2,"Name":"TypeOfFruit"},{"Index":3,"Name":"Color"},{"Index":3,"Name":"Taste"}],"Fruits":[{"Column1":"","Column2":"Mango","Column3":"Yellow"},{"Column1":"","Column2":"Coconut","Column3":"Green"},{"Column1":"","Column2":"Banana","Column3":"Yellow"},{"Column1":"","Column2":"Apple","Column3":"Red"},{"Column1":"","Column2":"Watermelon","Column3":"Green"}]}';
SET @appendnewjson='Column4:Sweet'

SELECT @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, CONCAT('$.Fruits[', [key], '].Column4'), 'sweet')
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.Fruits');
SELECT @json;
```

Would give you:

```
(Kein Spaltenname)
{
    "Heading": [{
        "Index": 1,
        "Name": "Empty"
    }, {
        "Index": 2,
        "Name": "TypeOfFruit"
    }, {
        "Index": 3,
        "Name": "Color"
    }, {
        "Index": 3,
        "Name": "Taste"
    }],
    "Fruits": [{
        "Column1": "",
        "Column2": "Mango",
        "Column3": "Yellow",
        "Column4": "sweet"
    }, {
        "Column1": "",
        "Column2": "Coconut",
        "Column3": "Green",
        "Column4": "sweet"
    }, {
        "Column1": "",
        "Column2": "Banana",
        "Column3": "Yellow",
        "Column4": "sweet"
    }, {
        "Column1": "",
        "Column2": "Apple",
        "Column3": "Red",
        "Column4": "sweet"
    }, {
        "Column1": "",
        "Column2": "Watermelon",
        "Column3": "Green",
        "Column4": "sweet"
    }]
}
```

But you need at least SQL Server 2017 for this.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but unfortunately I can only use SQL Server 2016, in which I believe that the JSON_PATH can only accept string literal. That's why I'm getting an error. "Msg 13610, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
The argument 2 of the "JSON_MODIFY" must be a string literal."

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by breaking open the `Fruits` property into separate rows, modifying each one, then re-aggregating them, and finally storing them back

```sql
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @json = '{"Heading":[{"Index":1,"Name":"Empty"},{"Index":2,"Name":"TypeOfFruit"},{"Index":3,"Name":"Color"},{"Index":3,"Name":"Taste"}],"Fruits":[{"Column1":"","Column2":"Mango","Column3":"Yellow"},{"Column1":"","Column2":"Coconut","Column3":"Green"},{"Column1":"","Column2":"Banana","Column3":"Yellow"},{"Column1":"","Column2":"Apple","Column3":"Red"},{"Column1":"","Column2":"Watermelon","Column3":"Green"}]}';

SELECT @json AS 'Before', 
    JSON_MODIFY(@json, '$.Fruits', JSON_QUERY((
        SELECT '[' + STRING_AGG(JSON_MODIFY(j.value, '$.Column4', 'Sweet'), ',') + ']'
        FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.Fruits') j
    ))) AS 'After';
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/163272)